# DialogFragment illegalstateException when showing from asynctasks

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-dialogfragment

1. I have an asyncTaks doing some background Operation resulting updating UI
2. The user starts the activity, and start an AsyncTask to do some background work.
3. The user taps home key to leave the application. onSaveInstanceState() is called.
4. The AsyncTask finishes, and try to show a DialogFragment or LoginFragment depending on result on  onPostexecute().
5. Since it performs the FragmentTransaction after onSaveInstance(). The IllegaeStateException occurs.
6. To deal with loginfragments i am calling commitAllowingStateLoss(); instead of commit(); . It solve the problem for loginfragment

My question is what should i do for my dialogfragment.

```
private void networkError(){
    NetowrkErrorDialog mErrorDialog = NetowrkErrorDialog.newInstance();
    mErrorDialog.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_NoActionBar_Fullscreen);
    mErrorDialog.setCancelable(false);
    if(mErrorDialog.isVisible()==false){
        mErrorDialog.show(mMainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "networkerror");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You AsyncTask must stop as soon as `onPause()` is called on the activity. Call `cancel(true)` on AsyncTask. User may return to your activity and start it again.

Or use [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

Comment: I want my asynctask to run on background as they are what for .

Comment: @SureshBora No, they are for background processing "while user sees your UI". For true background processing (when user is away from your UI), use Services, and notifications.

Comment: You probably don't want to cancel your AsyncTask in onPause, since the Activity is still visible at that point. And if you did it in onStop, it would be canceled during an orientation change, which is probably not desired either.